# ¿Cómo separo una cadena en varias subcadenas en diferentes columnas en SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-11g, plsql

Estoy trabajando con OracleXE, tengo unos archivos que tienen en sus nombres el carácter piso o underscore (`_`). Ejemplo:

```
uno_dos_tres_cuatro.csv
A_B_C_D.csv
arbol_mesa_pizza_oregano.csv
```

Quiero separar esos campos (de distinta longitud) en 4 columnas separadas.

Utilicé la siguiente expresión, pero esa sentencia solo me devuelve el primer campo de la cadena:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(NOMBRE_COMPLETO, '[^_]+[^_]+') FROM ARCHIVO;
```

Mi idea es que me devuelva los 4 campos, sin la extensión `.csv` al final:

```
| columna 1 | columna 2 | columna 3 | columna 4 |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| uno       | dos       | tres      | cuatro    |
| A         | B         | C         | D         |
| arbol     | mesa      | pizza     | oregano   |
```

---

Este es un ejemplo de mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla ("id" int, "nombre_archivo" varchar2(34));
INSERT ALL 
    INTO tabla ("id", "nombre_archivo")
         VALUES (1, 'uno_dos_tres_cuatro.csv')
    INTO tabla ("id", "nombre_archivo")
         VALUES (2, 'A_B_C_D.csv')
    INTO tabla ("id", "nombre_archivo")
         VALUES (3, 'arbol_mesa_pizza_oregano.csv')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Comment: No esos solo fueron ejemplos, son siempre 6 realmente, y al último debo quitarle el ". csv"... Quiero las cadenas que están entre cada underscore

Comment: Para el primer ejemplo debo obtener "uno dos tres cuatro" en campos distintos

Comment: Y tiene que ser con una regex?

Comment: No, como sea que puedas con una sentencia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Separar en columnas** (caso general)

Cuando el delimitador es **un único caracter**, buscamos que coincida con cualquier texto excepto el delimitador **`c`**:

```
[^c]*
```

- Ejemplo para `'_'`:

  ```
  REGEXP_SUBSTR( COLUMNA, '[^_]*', 1, &num_item )
  ```

  y cuando en el parámetro `&num_item` pasemos 1, nos devolverá el primer ítem al separar la cadena; 2 para el segundo, etc.

En cambio, si el delimitador tiene **más de un caracter**:

```
(.*?)(Texto Delimitador|$)
```

- Ejemplo para `'~~'`:

  ```
  REGEXP_SUBSTR( COLUMNA, '(.*?)(~~|$)', 1, &num_item, '', 1)
  ```

  El `1` en el último parámetro está diciendo que devuelva el texto que coincidió con el primer grupo de paréntesis.

En ambos casos, si se desea ignorar a los ítems vacíos (dos delimitadores seguidos), hay que cambiar el `*` por un `+`.

---

**Separar eliminando `.csv` del final**

La idea es que coincida:

- con todos los caracteres que no sean un guión bajo (`[^_]+`)
- hasta encontrarse con `(_|(\.csv)?$)`

  - un `_`, **o**
  - `(\.csv)?$` la extensión del archivo (opcional) seguida del fin del texto.

Entonces, tenemos el regex:

```
([^_]+?)(_|(\.csv)?$)
```

donde lo que nos interesa obtener es el texto del primer grupo (el primer conjunto de paréntesis).

Y pasamos ese regex a la función [**REGEXP_SUBSTR()**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303)

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( columna, regex, inicio, num_coincidencia, opciones, grupo)
```

- `num_coincidencia` lo vamos a ir cambiando para cada una de las 4 columnas.
- `grupo` será 1 (el texto que coincidió con los primeros paréntesis)

Código:

```sql
select REGEXP_SUBSTR( "nombre_archivo" ,'([^_]+?)(_|(\.csv)?$)', 1, 1, '', 1)
           AS "columna 1",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "nombre_archivo" ,'([^_]+?)(_|(\.csv)?$)', 1, 2, '', 1)
           AS "columna 2",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "nombre_archivo" ,'([^_]+?)(_|(\.csv)?$)', 1, 3, '', 1)
           AS "columna 3",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "nombre_archivo" ,'([^_]+?)(_|(\.csv)?$)', 1, 4, '', 1)
           AS "columna 4"
  from tabla
```

Resultado

```
| columna 1 | columna 2 | columna 3 | columna 4 |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| uno       | dos       | tres      | cuatro    |
| A         | B         | C         | D         |
| arbol     | mesa      | pizza     | oregano   |
```

Demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07d59/2/0